# In how many ways can $5$ different people be assigned to $3$ identical rooms if each room must have at least one person?

Tags: combinatorics

The possible cases are $3,1,1$ and $2,2,1$, so it will be $25$ ways.
I am confused. Is it right or wrong??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you should explain your reasoning so that people can check your work.

Comment: It's true as long as the five people are indistinguishable.  It's not clear whether calling them "different" people means that they are distinguishable.

Comment: @MatthewDaly: No, the answer is correct for distinguishable people. It's the rooms that are indistinguishable.

Comment: @joriki Hmmm, true.  I must have read that 25 as a 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. This is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), $\left\{5\atop3\right\}=25$, which counts the number of ways to partition a set of $5$ (distinguishable) elements into $3$ non-empty subsets.